# Dynamics CRM 365 Changing Sales Stage on Opportunity stopped working

Tags: dynamics-crm, stage

Users of our Dynamics Crm Application (8.2 onPrem) claim that since a couple of weeks ago it does no longer work to change the Sales Stage on Opportunity by clicking the stage.

It seems as if clicking on a stage makes the stage "marked" and it appears selected bu when closing and reopening the opportunity it is still in the previous stage.

However, clicking on "Next Stage" still seems to work. By clicking "Next Stage" the stage becomes marked (just like when clicking directly on the stage) but this time, when closing and reopening the case, the selected stage is correctly displayed.

We have a javascript function hooked up on the onStageChange event ( Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnStageChange(onStageChange);) and I can see that this function is executed when clicking "Next Stage" but not when clicking directly on the stage.

Has anyone encountered this problem and have an idea of what could be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between [selecting a stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/formcontext-data-process/eventhandlers/addonstageselected) and [changing stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/formcontext-data-process/eventhandlers/addonstagechange).
You are explaining the expected functionality. The stage does not change by simply selecting another stage. For this you have to select a previous stage and click *Set Active*, or click previous/next stage.

Do you have any custom logic inside your `onStageChange`-handler that has possibly stopped working?

Comment: Well, it's quite weird because the users claim clicking on a stage selected it. But there is no custom code to be found that would alter this behaviour, nor do I remember developing such functionality (I'm lead dev for this project).. So we'll write off this problem as a user imaginated error.. :) Thank You for confirming my perception of how it was supposed to work.